# Swift - How to append a specific attributed text at the end of a plain text, while not changing the attributes of the previous text on a TextView

Tags: swift, append, nsattributedstring

I try to append attributed text at the end of a plain text. In order to do this, I think I have to make all the textView.text as attributed and then set the textView.attributedText = combination. But when I do this, all the text at the previous lines get smaller font size, I didn't understand why. The code is below:

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\nANS = " + resultt + "\n")
attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: textView.font!.pointSize), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 6))
let combination = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text)
combination.append(attributedString)
textView.attributedText = combination
```

Comment: `let combination = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text)` => `let combination = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)`. Because you were recreating a `NSAttributedString` from a `String`, but a `String` doesn't have attributes for rendering, it's just a plain list of characters (to simplify).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lost the attributed data when creating `combination`.

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\nANS = " + resultt + "\n")
attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: textView.font!.pointSize), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 6))
// Pass the attributed string, not the plain one
let combination = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
combination.append(attributedString)
textView.attributedText = combination
```

Comment: thank you, this small trick was the point I was struggling:)

Answer (score 0):

Create the attributes

```
let textColor = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: <#T##color: UIColor##UIColor#>]
let linkColor = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: <#T##color: UIColor##UIColor#>]
let termsLinkAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.link: <#T##yourLink: String##String#>]
let policyLinkAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.link: <#T##yourLink: String##String#>]
```

Add the attributes to the different parts of the text

```
let firstText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: <#T##yourText: String##String#> + " ",
                                              attributes: textColor)
let secondText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: <#T##yourText: String##String#> + " ",
                                              attributes: textColor)
let termsLink = NSMutableAttributedString(string: <#T##yourText: String##String#> + " ",
                                              attributes: termsLinkAttributes)
let policyLink = NSMutableAttributedString(string: <#T##yourText: String##String#> + ".",
                                              attributes: policyLinkAttributes)

let finalText = NSMutableAttributedString()
finalText.append(firstText)     
finalText.append(termsLink)     
finalText.append(secondText)
finalText.append(policyLink)
```

Apply it to your TextView

```
<#T##yourTextView: UITextView##UITextView#>.delegate = self
<#T##yourTextView: UITextView##UITextView#>.linkTextAttributes = linkColor
<#T##yourTextView: UITextView##UITextView#>.attributedText = finalText
```